# How to use itenary operator?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have conditional `$stateParams` on `$state` and i am trying to assign current `$stateParams` value to `paramId`. How can i achieve that task using ternary operator?

commonCtrl.js

```
 var paramId = $stateParams.processId:? $stateParams.assessmentId;
```

config.js

```
.state('app.addPrcChallenge', {
            url: '/add/prcChallenge/:processId/:assessmentId?',
            templateUrl: 'views/process/processChallenge.html',
            controller: 'ProcessChallengesCtrl',
            data: {
                authenticate: true
            },
```

Comment: Side note - it's called a *ternary* operator

Comment: Side note - you can not place : and ? together

Answer (score 2):

You are close. Try this:

```
var paramId = $stateParams.processId ? $stateParams.processId : $stateParams.assessmentId;
```

Comment: why we assigning `$stateParams.processId` twice ?

Comment: @hussain - It's not assigning it twice.

Comment: You could use `||` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately javascript doesn't posses a [`null coalescing operator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) like C# does but you could achieve pretty much the same effect with this construct:

```
var paramId = $stateParams.processId || $stateParams.assessmentId;
```

Basically this means that `paramId` will equal to `$stateParams.processId` if it has some value different than `undefined` and equal to `$stateParams.assessmentId` otherwise.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?

Comment: I can't see one. I prefer your answer.